# Yahoo Currency API Java multiple currency requests

Tags: java, api, currency, yahoo, finance

I'm having trouble grabbing multiple currencies at once from yahoo, the code produces the
first request but not the second.

```
public double getRate(String from1, String to1, String from2, String to2) {

    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://quote.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?f=l1&s=" + from1 + to1 + "=X," + from2 + to2 + "=X");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

        String line = reader.readLine();
        if (line.length() > 0) {
            return Double.parseDouble(line);
        }

        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException | NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Best

Comment: Did you debug the line value?